# Need help to tokenize a model code on Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a model code, let's say A1234. I would like to be able to tokenize this in two ways:

```
Token 1: A1234
Token 2: 1234 (only numbers)
```

So, when I search, i can type both.

Also, I need to tokenize white spaces, so if I have let's say a model called A1234 Ferrari, i expect the output tokens to be

```
A1234, 1234, Ferrari
```

How can I achieve this? I tried some PatternTokenizerFactory but I couldn't reach my goal.

```
<tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="\s*|[0-9]+"/>
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: you can use the whitespacetokenizer along with wordgraphfilter factory would work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below field type for your field.

`preserveOriginal`: (integer, default 0) If non-zero, the original token is preserved

`splitOnNumerics` : (integer, default 1) If 0, don’t split words on transitions from alpha to numeric:

```
<fieldType name="custom_field_type" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="100">
       <analyzer type="index">
           <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
           <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory"
                   generateWordParts="1"
                   generateNumberParts="1"
                   preserveOriginal="1"
                   splitOnNumerics="1"
           />
           <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
       </analyzer>
       <analyzer type="query">
           <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
           <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
       </analyzer>
   </fieldType>
```

Comment: I had to add       <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" maxGramSize="100"/> to match cases like A1234B

Comment: EdgeNGramFilterFactory would be needed in case of A1234B...thats the correct